# How much time should a backup of a 100Gb database take using streaming server setup?

Tags: postgresql, backup, barman

I've installed barman on a dedicated server to backup all my postgresql servers. One of the server is now using 100Gb space and the instruction `barman backup myserver` takes 23 hours. I find it too long, but I have no reference points. Is it common? What should I investigate to improve such situation? Here are the settings for streaming the server

```
; ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Backup settings (via pg_basebackup)
; ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
backup_method = postgres
;streaming_backup_name = barman_streaming_backup

; ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; WAL streaming settings (via pg_receivexlog)
; ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
streaming_archiver = on
slot_name = barman
;streaming_archiver_name = barman_receive_wal
;streaming_archiver_batch_size = 50


minimum_redundancy = 3
last_backup_maximum_age = '3 DAYS'
retention_policy = 'RECOVERY WINDOW OF 16 DAYS'
```

Comment: How fast is the network connection between the servers?

Comment: Using iperf3 I get the following results:[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec   453 MBytes   380 Mbits/sec   76             sender
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec   449 MBytes   377 Mbits/sec                  receiver

Download
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  30.0 MBytes  25.2 Mbits/sec   97             sender
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  29.6 MBytes  24.8 Mbits/sec                  receiver.

Comment: I suppose that the speed to be taken into consideration is 25 Mbits/sec. So if I'm not wrong, the backup should last around one hour.

Comment: I get a little over 9 hours. Remember there are 8 bits in a byte.  Also, what if you run iPerf3 in "-R" mode?

Comment: 25Mbits/sec is the result obtained using "-R" mode.

Answer (score 1):

You are plausibly in the range where network bandwidth is limiting.  I get 9 hours versus your reported 23, but that could be accounted for by overhead, inefficiencies or competing network usage.

You can try turning on network compression, which requires changing the backup method, which in turn will require you to configure "ssh_command".

```
ssh_command=ssh postgres@192.168.0.15
backup_method = rsync
network_compression=true
```

Of course this will impose some CPU overhead on the server for it to do the compression.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will try the scenario you propose to see if I get similar results to yours.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario using ssh instead of streaming_archive is better, backup time less than 2 hours, compression diminish needed space of one third. Here is the settings I've used:

```
ssh_command = ssh postgres@conn_host
conninfo = host=conn_host user=conn_user dbname=conn_db
backup_method = rsync
reuse_backup = link
archiver = on
network_compression = true
minimum_redundancy = 3
last_backup_maximum_age = '3 DAYS'
retention_policy = 'RECOVERY WINDOW OF 31 DAYS'
wal_retention_policy = main
```